# Unable to insert row into table with constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following definition of table in my Database

```
CREATE TABLE Products
  (
    PartNo      CHAR (6) NOT NULL ,
    Description VARCHAR2 (16) NOT NULL ,
    Weight      SMALLINT NOT NULL
  ) ;
ALTER TABLE Products ADD CONSTRAINT CK_PartNo CHECK ( PartNo LIKE '[0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]') ;
ALTER TABLE Products ADD CONSTRAINT Products_PK PRIMARY KEY ( PartNo ) ;
```

When I try to insert a row I get an error of not meeting the constraint check.

```
insert into PRODUCTS(PARTNO, DESCRIPTION, WEIGHT)
values('1W1234', 'O-ring', 1);
```

```
*Action:   do not insert values that violate the constraint.
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
insert into PRODUCTS(PARTNO, DESCRIPTION, WEIGHT)
values('1W1234', 'O-ring', 1)
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02290: check constraint (DEMO.CK_PARTNO) violated
02290. 00000 -  "check constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    The values being inserted do not satisfy the named check
```

Comment: LIKE doesnt't know regexp - try REGEXP_LIKE function (but i'am not sure if check constranits support this function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use regular expression syntax in a `LIKE`, you need to use `REGEXP_LIKE`:

```
CHECK ( REGEXP_LIKE(PARTNO, '[0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```

Demo:

```
CREATE TABLE Products
  (
    PartNo      CHAR (6) NOT NULL ,
    Description VARCHAR2 (16) NOT NULL ,
    Weight      SMALLINT NOT NULL
  ) ;
ALTER TABLE Products ADD CONSTRAINT CK_PartNo
  CHECK ( REGEXP_LIKE(PARTNO, '[0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]') ) ;
ALTER TABLE Products ADD CONSTRAINT Products_PK PRIMARY KEY ( PartNo ) ;

insert into PRODUCTS(PARTNO, DESCRIPTION, WEIGHT)
values('1W1234', 'O-ring', 1);

1 rows inserted.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ALTER TABLE Products ADD CONSTRAINT CK_PartNo 
  CHECK ( regexp_like(PartNo, '\d[A-Z]\d{4}') ) ;
```